# How toget node attributes value by its name in php simplexml?

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml

my basic xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
    <user userId="1"  userName="nameHere" userAge="34"></user>
</users>
```

and then:

How can I get the special attribute's value by its name? Just like :

```
variable value = user.attr('userAge')
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use on `attributes()` method,
such as

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<users>
  <user userId="1"  userName="nameHere" userAge="34"></user>
</users>');
$userAge = (int) $xml->user->attributes()->userAge;
```